# Json-server GET request not found

Tags: node.js, json

I manage to display the data in my db.json file, however when I try to access individual item by specifying the ID -> localhost:8000/projects/1 it displays Not Found.
My db.json is listening on port:8000 while my react app is on port:3000

### [image]

### **Error when i click onto indiv projects:**
[image]
[image]

---

**Localhost:8000/projects/1:**
[image]

These are my files:

**projectList.js**: This file formats each data

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const ProjectList = ({ projectProp, titleProp, handleDelete }) => {
  // Destructing {projectProp & titleProp}
  const projects = projectProp;
  //   const title = props.title;

  return (
    <div className="project-list">
      <h2>{titleProp}</h2>
      {projects.map((project) => (
        <div className="project-preview" key={project.id}>
          <Link to={`/projects/${project.id}`}>
            <h2>{project.title}</h2>
            <p>{project.body}</p>
          </Link>
          <button onClick={() => handleDelete(project.id)}>
            Delete project
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectList;
```

**projectDetails.js**: This file routes to a link -> projects/{id} when i click on each item

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";
const ProjectDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log("Requesting project with ID:", id);
  const url = "http://localhost:8000/projects/" + id;
  const { data: project, error, isPending } = useFetch(url);
  console.log(url);

  return (
    <div className="project-details">
      {isPending && <div> Loading...</div>}
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      {project && (
        <article>
          <h2>{project.title}</h2>
          <div>{project.body}</div>
        </article>
      )}
      project with id {id}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectDetails;
```

**Home.js:**

```
import ProjectList from "./ProjectList";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";
const Home = () => {
  //const [projects, setProjects] = useState(null);
  const {
    data: projects,
    isPending,
    error,
  } = useFetch("http://localhost:8000/projects");

  return (
    <div className="home">
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {projects && (
        <ProjectList
          projectProp={projects}
          titleProp="All projects"
          /*handleDelete={handleDelete}*/
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**data/db.json:**

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "1st Project",
      "body": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "2nd Project",
      "body": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "3rd Project",
      "body": "Hello"
    }
  ]
}
```

useFetch.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            console.log(res);
            throw Error("Could not fetch data for that resource"); /*if no res*/
          }
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setData(data);
          setIsPending(false);
          setError(null);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError(err.message);
          setIsPending(false);
        });
    }, 1000);
  }, [url]);

  return {
    data,
    isPending,
    error,
  }; /*returning these properties so it is usable*/
};

export default useFetch;
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
            <Route path="/project" element={<Project />}></Route>
            <Route path="/create" element={<Create />}></Route>
            <Route path="/projects/:id" element={<ProjectDetails />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Show your react routes configuration.

Comment: @LinDu i've attached my App.js file!

Comment: Your react app server is running on `http://localhost:3000`, why do you access the `http://localhost:8000/projects/1`?

Comment: I was trying to see if i could get the item by ID on port:8000 because on the react app it is producing an error as show on 1st image @LinDu

Comment: Can you show how you use `json-server` cli and the logs?

Comment: json-server --watch data/db.json --port 8000, apparently I dont get a GET response in the logs so i've attached the image of the error on the console log 
Result: 
JSON Server started on PORT :8000
Press CTRL-C to stop
Watching data/db.json...

♡⸜(˶˃ ᵕ ˂˶)⸝♡

Index:
http://localhost:8000/

Static files:
Serving ./public directory if it exists

Endpoints:
http://localhost:8000/projects

Comment: It works fine for me. What's the version of `json-server`？

Comment: youre able to get single item when clicked? im using node.js v20.0.0 & my package.json is  "version": "0.1.0" @LinDu

Comment: I am using `"json-server": "^0.17.0"`, it works fine.

Comment: hm im not sure is it due to the version im using that is causing the issue @lin

Comment: Duplicate, with a much simpler [mre]: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77798989/3001761

Comment: ah thank you so much! couldnt find the solution anywhere! @jonrsharpe

Comment: No problem @HelpAGirlOut - if you found the answer useful enough for an upvote I could propose that Q as an actual duplicate and link them together.