# Using integers for IDs created "Not found" error in JSON server

Tags: json-server

I installed `json-server` using npm. And created a `students.json` file to practise API testing, but when I used `http://localhost:3000/students/2` to get a student details with id value 2 it gives not found error, but if I changed id value to string it works perfectly fine, and the tutorial I was following was also using int as value. Why it is not working for me?

Here is my `students.json`:

```json
{
    "students": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Soze",
            "location": "Portland",
            "phone": "9987568",
            "Courses": [
                "Python",
                "Java"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Isabelle",
            "location": "Seattle",
            "phone": "2345678",
            "Courses": [
                "JavaScript",
                "C++"
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of `json-server`<sup>1</sup> does not support non-string IDs for entities. Per [`typicode/json-server#1473`](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1473):

> it's intentional :) It's easier to manage and removes some internal complexity

So either:

- Install the stable version, `npm install json-server@0`, to correspond with whatever tutorial you're following; or
- (As you noted works) switch your IDs to strings:

  ```json
  {
      "students": [
          {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "Soze",
              "location": "Portland",
              "phone": "9987568",
              "Courses": [
                  "Python",
                  "Java"
              ]
          },
          {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "Isabelle",
              "location": "Seattle",
              "phone": "2345678",
              "Courses": [
                  "JavaScript",
                  "C++"
              ]
          }
          ]
  }
  ```

v1 also generates four-character hexadecimal string IDs on entity creation, rather than the old behaviour of incrementing numerical IDs: [`typicode/json-server#1477`](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1477).

---

<sup>1</sup> *`1.0.0-alpha.16` - publishing of alpha versions has caused some problems, e.g. [Unexpected errors and warnings when running json-server --watch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77787616/3001761)*