# Json server errors. How can i correct the 404 errors logged after Patching and Deleting data-Items?

Tags: patch, json-server

I am trying the patch and delete operations to  json-server and am getting a 404 error from the server. My (db.json file) is as follows:

```js
{
  "items": [
    {
      "groceryItem": "Mango",
      "id": 1,
      "checked": false
    },
    {
      "groceryItem": "pawpaw",
      "id": 2,
      "checked": false
    },
    {
      "groceryItem": "WaterMelon",
      "id": 3,
      "checked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "checked": false,
      "groceryItem": "Pineapple"
    }
  ]
}
```

The stateless function component that runs the crud operations is as follows...

```js
const Apirequests = async (url = "", optionsObj = null, errmessage = null) => {
   try {
       const resp = await fetch(url, optionsObj);
       if (!resp.ok) throw Error(`Please reload the webpage`);
   } catch (err) {
       errmessage = err.message;
   } finally {
       return errmessage;
   }
};

export default Apirequests;
```

After importing the SFC my patch operation is as follows(This updates the checkbox such that when checked it updates to true and when unchecked it defaults back to false )..

```js
const handleChange = async (id) => {
    const newGroceries = groceries.map((grocery) =>
        grocery.id === id ? { ...grocery, checked: !grocery.checked } : grocery
    );
    setGroceries(newGroceries);

    const myGrocery = newGroceries.filter((grocery) => grocery.id === id);
    const updateOptions = {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ checked: myGrocery[0].checked }),
    };

    const requiredUrl = `${API_URL}/${id}`;
    const result = await Apirequests(requiredUrl, updateOptions);
    if (result) setFetchError(result);
    console.log("PATCH URL:", requiredUrl);
    console.log("PATCH Headers:", updateOptions.headers);
    console.log("PATCH Body:", updateOptions.body);
};
```

My delete operation is as follows(This updates the json-server when a list item is deleted)

```js
const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    const newGroceries = groceries.filter((grocery) => grocery.id !== id);
    setGroceries(newGroceries);

    const DeleteOptions = {
        method: "DELETE",
    };
    const requiredUrl = `${API_URL}/${id}`;
    console.log(requiredUrl);
    const result = await Apirequests(requiredUrl, DeleteOptions);
    if (result) setFetchError(result);
};
```

I have tried resetting the json-server to no progress. The 404 errors persist for the PATCH and DELETE operations. The POST operation(which adds a new list item) works perfectly

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77798989/3001761