# Unable to access ID keys and GET request

Tags: node.js, json, json-server

I can't access the `db.json` file id keys in the localhost port URL even though it should work.

I've downloaded the JSON Server node package on my Ubuntu via this code:

```
$ npm install -g json-server
```

I could start the server using the command `json-server db.json` but not `json-server --watch db.json`.

I can access the endpoint http://localhost:3000/articles but if I access the id keys http://localhost:3000/articles/1
The browser throws a 'Not found' error and the terminal throws me this error:

```
EtaError [Eta Error]: Could not find template: /home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/views/index.html
    at Eta.readFile (file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/eta/dist/eta.module.mjs:570:13)
    at Eta.handleCache (file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/eta/dist/eta.module.mjs:434:35)
    at Eta.render (file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/eta/dist/eta.module.mjs:460:30)
    at file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/app.js:29:46
    at file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/@tinyhttp/app/dist/index.js:171:7
    at file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/@tinyhttp/app/dist/index.js:434:34
    at loop (file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/@tinyhttp/app/dist/index.js:437:81)
    at next (file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/@tinyhttp/app/dist/index.js:438:66)
    at file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/milliparsec/dist/index.js:25:9
    at file:///home/emilychew/.nvm/versions/node/v20.9.0/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/@tinyhttp/app/dist/index.js:169:13
```

If I try to fetch a GET request, the active JSON server doesn't show the GET request in the terminal (as shown in picture)

[db.json file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsrKT.png)
[Terminal and index,js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps84f.png)

Am I missing something?

I've tried reinstalling the JSON server package, but it is still the same.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77798989/3001761

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe! I've uninstalled it and installed the stable version @0.17.4 pre alpha version and everything is running smoothly. Cheers!

Comment: No problem; I'd propose as a dupe but that needs an upvoted or accepted answer.