# Integer "id" value automatically gets updated to string after POST method

Tags: json-server

The integer `id` value got automatically converted to string after executing `json-server db.json`

I created a simple `db.json` that stores the user data like this:

```json
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "User1",
      "email": "test.user1@fakemail.com",
      "number": "08100000000"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "User2",
      "email": "test.user2@fakemail.com",
      "number": "08111111111"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "User3",
      "email": "test.user3@fakemail.com",
      "number": "09022222222"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "User4",
      "email": "test.user4@fakemail.com",
      "number": "09033333333"
    },
```

Next, I updated the file to add another user using the `POST` command via Postman:

```json
{
    "name": "User5",
    "email": "test.user5@fakemail.com",
    "number": "987876757534"
}
```

I expected the `id` to be 5 but it was a random string value `"da4a"`. Also, I noticed that that all `id` values were converted to string, for example `"id": "4"`, after the `json-server db.json`.

I initially had the latest `json-server` version installed when I noticed this issue. I uninstalled it and installed the older version `npm i json-server@0.17.4` but the `id` value is still automatically converted to string, and the `id` value is also automatically converted to random string value.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77798989/3001761 - that would _not_ happen with v0.