localhost:5000/todos/id 404 (Not Found)
I have a simple todo list with react and redux toolkit and json-server(for data base) that I can get todos And there is no problem adding new todo to db.json by axios in createAsyncThunk and UI updated in exteraReducer . But when I want to delete a todo from db.json by createAsyncThunk and exteraReducer in createSlice I get 404 ERROR.
Also, when I type URL http://localhost:5000/todos it's ok and I can see data of db.json. But when I type http://localhost:5000/todos/id I get not found error.
I put this code on github: https://github.com/nahid-allahparast/todo-list-redux-toolkit
<button
className="btn btn-danger"
onClick={() => dispatch(deleteAsyncTodos({ id }))}
>
delete
</button>

Base URL:
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
});

Delete from db.json:
export const deleteAsyncTodos = createAsyncThunk(
"todos/deleteAsyncTodos",
async (payload, { rejectWithValue }) => {
try {
await api.delete(`/todos/${payload.id}`);
return { id: payload.id };
} catch (error) {
return rejectWithValue(error.message);
}
}
);


Show the result in the UI by exteraReducer:
const todoSlice = createSlice({
name: "todos",
initialState: {
todos: [],
loading: false,
error: "",
},
extraReducers: (builder) => {
builder
.addCase(deleteAsyncTodos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
state.todos = state.todos.filter(
(todo) => todo.id !== Number(action.payload.id)
);
})
});


How are you building and running or serving the app? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve].

This question is similar to: Using integers for IDs created "Not found" error in JSON server. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The problem was with jason-server and it was fixed when I installed npm install json-server@0
thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77801181/16772408
